# Two Records Appear from inserted virtual table using a trigger

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, triggers

I am trying to keep a log of the date and time when users log on.

I have created a trigger with the idea, when a user logs in the LastActivityDate changes, I then insert this into my audit log on table to track when users have logged on. The issue I get is every time a user logs on it updates my audit table, but passes through two entries with slightly different times.

```
INSERT Audit_UserLogOn
    (UserId
      ,LogOnDateTime)
    

SELECT TOP(1) i.UserId
      ,i.LastActivityDate
  FROM inserted i
  WHERE i.LastActivityDate <> (Select d.LastActivityDate FROM deleted d)
```

Results are:

| UserID | LogOnDateTime |
| --- | --- |
| D604A | 2022-10-24 10:23:59.187 |
| D604A | 2022-10-24 10:23:59.187 |

I am guessing this is something to do with it creating a timestamp when it deletes the original record and another when it inserts the new, but how can I prevent this inserting both and only get the one record?

Thanks in advance of you response.

Comment: my guess is that your update changes two rows not one as expected, but for that we must see the code reduced to the problem

Comment: The DBMS is SQL Server. The code is on the trigger as above:  `INSERT Audit_UserLogOn (UserId ,LogOnDateTime)

SELECT TOP(1) i.UserId ,i.LastActivityDate FROM inserted i WHERE i.LastActivityDate <> (Select d.LastActivityDate FROM deleted d)` Many thanks